# JSON format for sending events for Azure IoT Central

Tags: c++, json, azure-iot-central

I'm trying to send an Event from a device to an Azure IoT Central hub.

Sending telemetry data works, but I'm not seeing a response when I try to send an event and I'm pretty sure it's due to not knowing the correct JSON format to use.
Does anyone know the correct format and objects you need to fill in to send an event? Is this documented somewhere I might have missed?

Thanks for your help, let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Please enter a example of your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What was the command used?

Comment: The JSON string I tried sending to Azure was `{"picTaken":"TestImage.jpg"}`.

Comment: Nope, I meant to ask about the medium used to perform the operation. Which Azure SDK and module/method are you using?

Comment: If so, please include your code snippet in the question.

Comment: Oh sure. I was using C++ on an embedded board using [this library](https://github.com/gloveboxes/Connecting-Particle-Photon-to-Azure-IoT-Hub).
None of the examples document how to send Events, and I presumed there was a common JSON format I'd need to follow that I'm missing.